# c# exception thrown inside relaycommand unhandled by try catch inspite of try catch

Tags: c#, exception, relaycommand

I stumbled upon a weird exception problem while working on test methods. Basically, i throw an exception inside an if statement which isn't catched by the try-catch above it. All seems to be related to the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand and a line *after* the exception is thrown. Here are some code snippets if you guys want to reproduce the problem :
Here is my test method

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestRelayCommand()
        {
            TestEditVM t = new TestEditVM();
            bool argumentNullExceptionCatched = false;
            try
            {
                t.lists.Add(new MyObject());
                t.MyCommand.Execute(null);
                //t.MethodToTest();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                argumentNullExceptionCatched = true;
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(argumentNullExceptionCatched);
        }
```

and here is my TestEditVM along with a small class used by it

```
class TestEditVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyObject> lists = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
        public void MethodToTest()
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 1;
            int k = 1;

            i++;
            //throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (j == k)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("lorem", "ipsum");
            i++;

            //throw new ArgumentNullException();
            var lvm = (lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.IsQueryOwner(null)));
        }

        private RelayCommand _myCommand;
        public RelayCommand MyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_myCommand == null)
                {
                    _myCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        int j = 1;
                        int k = 1;

                        i++;
                        //throw new ArgumentNullException();
                        if (j == k)
                            throw new ArgumentNullException("lorem", "ipsum");
                        i++;

                        //throw new ArgumentNullException();
                        var lvm = (lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.IsQueryOwner(null)));
                    }
                    );
                }
                return _myCommand;
            }
        }
}
class MyObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public MyObject Query { get; set; }
        public bool IsQueryOwner(MyObject query)
        {
            if (query == null)
                throw new Exception("MyObject exception");

            return Query.Id == query.Id;
        }
    }
```

If i comment out the LinQ line, the exception is thrown and catched as expected. The same code running Inside TestMethod1() always behaves normally.

Also, i noticed that if one of the "throw" statements are uncommented, the code behaves as expected and the exception is catched. I believe this is some work done by the compiler to not include unreachable code during the execution (i.e. the bogus linq line)

I am running this test project on VisualStudio 2013, on .net Framework 4.5 with the latest mvvm light Framework available on NuGet.

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked what kind of exception the Linq query is? You only catch ArgumentNullException, which would make me think it might not be that?

Comment: @Bob I also tested with a simple catch, which doesn't help...
Also, while debugging, i can confirm that the unhandled exception is indeed an ARgumentNullException which contains my custom "lorem" "ipsum" param. weird! o_O

Comment: Perhaps, it would clarify things to say i never do get to run the Linq because the exception is thrown beforehand